# Generate a 3rd column sequential number based on two columns data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I apologize if the title is misleading, but 
I have an issue where I need to generate a sequential number in a third column based on comparing data from two different columns.

My data looks like this:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1r3Y.png)

The entry with the 1 is the first point, I need to use the value in the 'Back' column to find the same value in the 'Front' Column, then add +1 to the point, so the result looks like:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnwKG.png)

Because of the naming conventions used, sorting either column by value will not work.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean by the 'point'  What determines that the 1 goes in the last row on your before example?

Comment: I think unless you use a heap of dummy columns to work it out sequentially, I think you will need a macro. I can maybe look at a formula for the columns if you want

Comment: Hi Chris,That entry is the very first point in a sequence of points, but it is buried about halfway down my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the initial 1, and your number column is C, front is D, back is E, this would start at row 2:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(D2,E:E,0),1),D:D,0),1)+1
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZxUo.png

Comment: How does not that end up with a circular reference error? Awesome formula mate

Comment: @BryanDavies I gave up expecting logic and reason from Excel a long time ago :)

Comment: I think if excel went I must find the answer for C2 first, then realised to answer C2 it needs to answer C4 and to get C4 it needs C3 etc etc, and because you, in the end, refer to a specific cell and not a range, it sorta just works it out. But it really doesn't feel right

Comment: Hi Zerk,  that worked and it didn't work.  For some reason instead of getting a series of number from 1-1000, I am getting a lot of 1-4's or 1-10's.

Comment: Match takes the first result it finds in the column so my first assumption is that you may have duplicates in the data, this would change both the question and the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you establish whether your data has duplicates or incomplete sequences?

Here's another formula which should achieve what you want and also doesn't rely on you knowing where the sequence starts. Every sequence will start with 1.

This formula follows your image layout, putting values into column A with data in columns B and C. Please replace the ranges in the formula for columns A and C to cover all of your data. (Ideally, you would do this by inserting a table first and then selecting the data rows, which will cause Excel to put in the table column name instead.)

This is the formula to go into cell A2, assuming you have data in B2:C7

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$7,0)),1,INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$7,0))+1)
```

Put this formula in D2 and fill down to identify which rows are the ends of sequences:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(C2,$B$2:$B$7,0))
```

Put this formula in E2 and fill down to identify duplicates in the Front column:

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:B$7,B2)
```

You can then fill it right one column to also identify duplicates in Back.